# "Failure: require-capability: not granted" How do I grant a capability to my module?

Tags: pact-lang

I've got a very simple function (increase-count), and I do not want this to be callable by anybody except code in the module. For this, I am using (require-capability (PRIVATE)). As expected, I get the following error.

`Error from (api.testnet.chainweb.com): : Failure: require-capability: not granted: (free.guard-test-01.PRIVATE)`

How do I grant my module the PRIVATE capability?

```
(defcap PRIVATE ()
    true
)



(defun increase-count (key:string)
    ;increase the count of a key in a table by 1
    (require-capability (PRIVATE))
    (update counts-table key {"count": (+ 1 (get-count key))})
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

surround the call `increase-count` like this:

```
(with-capability (PRIVATE) (increase-count "abc"))
```

more in general:

- `(with-capability (CAP) expr)` will evaluate `CAP` to see whether you can grant it (this is the place where acquisition can fail), and then expr will be evaluated with `CAP` in scope if you successfully acquire it.
- `(require-capability (CAP))`  is then what you use within the scope of the functions you're trying to enforce CAP is present before you can proceed